# PHP blocking code, blocks the response of next ajax call also in Zend Server

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, zend-framework

I am facing a strange issue. Consider I have a ajax call like ;

```
$.ajax({

    url:"url1.php",

})
```

After this ajax call I have an second ajax call as,

```
$.ajax({

     url:"url2.php",

     success:function(data){console.log(data);}
})
```

url1.php as follow;

```
 $sql="SELECT * from db/tbl";
 echo $sql;

$_SESSION["filename"]=$time;
$_SESSION["detail-status"]="Data fetching will start";
$_SESSION["status"]="starting";

if (!($stmt = db2_exec($this->db2conn, $sql, array('CURSOR' => DB2_SCROLLABLE))))
{
    echo $sql."<b>Error ".db2_stmt_error() .":".db2_stmt_errormsg(). "</b>";
    die;
}
while ($row = db2_fetch_assoc($stmt))
{
    //........
}
```

url2.php as follow;

```
<?php
 session_start();
 echo "hello world";
?>
```

Now I have a blocking code in **url1**(i.e. fetching a huge amount data from db[IBM DB2]). Now issue is that I am not getting any response from **url2** in second ajax call until my first ajax call is completed.
In Chrome network tab showing status of second ajax call is *pending*. In back end the server is Zend server, in which I don't have any access.

Can you please give an insight why is this happening?

If you need any more information please mention.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/getting-started/primers/promises

Comment: What is this? Did you read what I asked?

Comment: Sorry, my fault. These are session locks. Just google that and start your journey ;) If you can share more context, maybe I'm able to explain some concepts and help.

Comment: hmm .. could be session locks, or bad server configuration to handle multiple requests, check this : http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/worker.html

Comment: @MateuszSip which kind of details you need?I have added some code details. Anyway I am looking for session lock.

Comment: Are request for `url1` and `url2` related? Does `url1` use session for anything other than auth? If it's something reporting-related, maybe you can just close session asap?

Comment: yes it does. I forget to write the most vital line I think. I have updated the url2.php code a bit just. Please take a look.

Comment: Ok, I think now I understand the issue. The session_start in url2.php is waiting until execution of url1.php is completed. Thank you a lot. A new thing to learn for me. :D

Answer (score -2):

Ajax calls are by definition **asynchronous** which means their requests are handled separately. That's why you have your callback functions or Promise objects in Javascript to handle the next step after the response has been received. So you should include your next ajax call in the **success** property in the first Ajax call.

Comment: You don't even understand my question. I never asked that.

Comment: What code is on the server side? How do you know it's blocking. Does it send back response if called on its own without first call.

Comment: I wrote what code in server side, it is fetching a huge amount data from db.

Comment: Well if the server doesn't have enough memory, it will stall. I meant if you send 2nd ajax without the 1st call, does it get response back.